# Custom notification when app in background or close

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

Is it possible to create an notification when my app in background all close.

What I mean:
If my app goes to background at some point at time I want to get notification with alert view on main screen in iPhone.

Alert view have to contain my custom description text.

Is it possible? and if this is possible that wich verion iOS should provide this option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a local notification.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Local notifications were introduced in iOS 4.0

Comment: thanks for response! can i use custom alert view instead standard UIAlertView?

Comment: It's up to the user.  If they are on iOS5.0 and are using the notification center they can control if it displays the alert view style or the notification banner.